# Force php to display number as 0.000001 instead of f 1.0E-6

Tags: php, number-formatting

I want to force php to output the number as a decimal number, not 1E-6. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`printf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php): `printf("%0.6f", $var);` Alternatively, `sprintf` returns a string rather than printing directly to the output.

Comment: wouldn't be `echo sprintf('%f', $foo);` enough ?

Comment: @Rufinus: same difference. `echo sprintf(...);` is the same as just `printf(...);`. `echo` and `printf` both write to the same output.

Comment: @Rufinus: Oh, I see. No idea, I don't know if the OP was specific about his precision requirements. `%f` just gives you the default. In C, the default has not leading `0`, though in PHP it appears that there is a leading zero even if you don't specify one. I guess it's nice to be able to be definite about one's formatting desires, and `printf` is widespread among so many languages that I thought it'd be useful to spell it out.